# Is there any means of using a GIS (Geographic Information System) in Apache Cordova?

Tags: cordova, gis, apache-cordova

I am planning to create a GIS based systems, and I want to use it in mobile approach using Apache Cordova or Phonegap. Is this even possible? Can you give me some clue or a place to start?

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to try [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/), I have seen that in different applications with Cordova and Phonegap but I don't know the specifics. Other web mapping frameworks are OpenLayers or Mapbox GL.

Comment: I was not paying attention to this question. I have diverted from this functionality but thanks anyway. :)

Comment: You might want to have look at [GIS stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) as well...